# Can't include my folders in the executable .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have some folders, where I have the soundtracks, images... I need for my game. Now, when I try to make an executable .jar File, Eclipse doesn't include these folders.

What can I do?[Here is a pic of the folders, if it helps :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DkxR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include these files as your resources, you need to add them to the `src/main/resources` directory.

This article may help https://www.codexpedia.com/java/java-packaging-resource-files-into-a-runnable-jar-file/

Answer (score 1):

Try to include your resources folder in the src/main folder.